# Dealing with the science tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tag-synonyms

I've been keeping my eye on the [science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) tag for the last couple of months. It has something of an odd history; at first, it was applied to questions about how a society treats, thinks of, and carries out science. An example of such a question is [Why would magic and science be split?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/27819/627).

The problem is, lately (meaning the last few questions which have used it) it seems to be misapplied, used in lieu of the [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based) tag. I considered adding it as a synonym, but I thought that the three or so questions that used it as it was originally intended used it well. On the other hand, that's a really small number of questions!

What do we think? Should we synonymize it with [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based) and remove it from these three questions, let it be, or do something else entirely?

---

For what it's worth, I feel that [science-fiction](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction) is being similarly severely misapplied (i.e. being used where [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based) should be), which is indicative of the same problem - which is why I've brought the issue up on meta. Any thoughts on that - and, more importantly, how to *fix* that - are also welcome.

### Excerpts

[science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based)

> For questions that require answers based in hard science, not magic or pseudo-science, but do not require scientific citations. Consider alternatively the hard-science and reality-check tags. Avoid using this tag as the only tag on a question.

[science-fiction](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction)

> For questions relating to worlds with a setting of common science-fiction.

[science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science)

No excerpt currently.

Comment: Bottom line is that science fiction is science based. Otherwise it's just fiction, right?

Comment: I added the excerpts to the question.  It seems that suggesting alternative excerpts should be in scope as a solution.  I'm not sure what the [tag:science-fiction] excerpt means, and [tag:science] doesn't have an excerpt.  If you'd prefer that as a separate question, you can of course roll back.

Comment: @Vincent Most people wouldn't really say that *Star Wars* is "science-based". Most people *would* say that *Star Wars* is science fiction. There are, of course, people who vociferously say that it's not "real" or "true" science fiction, but according to common usage - that is, what the vast majority of people mean when they say "science fiction" - it certainly is.

Answer (score 6):

It might just be my opinion, but, [science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science), [science-fiction](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction) and [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based) are really different subjects. The first one refers to a methodology and/or an academic subject, the second to a genre for various supports, or maybe a sub-culture. And the last is a meta-tag used by the OP to indicate the kind of answers they are expecting.

So aliases would be wrong IMHO. I don't think that's the right way to go.

Now, if tags have been misused, we should correct them, and make sure everyone knows the correct use of the tag. So re-tag and clarify tag-wikis.

Comment: But what would be a legitimate use of the science-fiction tag **on worldbuilding** where the science-based tag would not be more appropriate?

Comment: @celtschk *How does the Force affects the political landscape in the Star Wars Universe*. This is not a good question, but you get the idea. Star Wars is Science Fiction, it is about worldbuilding, but not science-based. At least I would not tag it Science-based.

Comment: ^ this. Those tags are entirely different and should ***NOT*** be synonyms at all. Misuses should be corrected.