# Revisiting the "science" tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, retagging

The [science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) tag is for:

> Questions about science and **the perception of science in a fictional world**. Use [science-based] for questions on how to explain fictional things based on real-world science. Use tags relating to specific fields (such as for example [space-exploration], [astronomy], [biology], [xenobiology], [mathematics], [sociology], ...) for questions relating to particular fields of science.

Emphasis mine.

Initially, the tag usage was consistent with this definition; users asked how people would treat science in a set of given circumstances. However, usage quickly departed from this definition.

As noted by the relevant meta discussion [Dealing with the science tag](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3680/dealing-with-the-science-tag), many people tag [science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) when they have a question that deals with scientific explanations, but isn't necessarily about the study of science itself. The meta discussion had one solution to this problem:

> Now, if tags have been misused, we should correct them, and make sure everyone knows the correct use of the tag. So re-tag and clarify tag-wikis.

However, it's been nearly 4 years since that discussion, and over 300 questions have the [science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) tag. No one re-tagged, and now the popular usage, imo, clearly defies the tag wiki. I think **the tag wiki has been insufficient to promote proper usage** because a) so many questions have already been mistagged, and b) the tag name itself is **just too ambiguous**.

I propose that we either

1. **Delete the [science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) tag**, since the large majority of questions with this tag defy the original definition. Salvaging it arguably might not be useful.
2. **Update the tag wiki to include questions that *use* science, not just questions *about* in-world science.** This course of action assumes that tag definitions do or should change with usage, not the other way around. It also assumes that there is a clear distinction between [science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) questions about using science and [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based) questions about using science so keeping the [science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) tag would create a meaningful distinction.
3. **Rename the tag to [science-in-society](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-in-society)** to accurately reflect its wiki and original use. Then remove it from irrelevant questions.

What seems like the most reasonable course of action? Alternatively this might be a non-issue so no course of action is needed. Or the original suggestion of retagging existing questions could work if someone commits to doing so, but imo we still need a less ambiguous name.

Comment: For clarity could you please explain how the usage of the tag defies its original definition. What about applying both 2 and 3 together? This would create a new tag based on its wiki & original use.

Comment: @a4android The original definition of the "science" tag pertains to how societies interpret it, whereas today, most people use it for "science-based" questions.

Comment: Thank you. So essentially a sociological perspective on the nature of science. Could it deal with how science might be affected by this (given) worldbuilding element type of questions? Just wondering.

Comment: @a4android Yeah, I think so. My issue is that right now, people apply it more at a meta "how do I use science to design this creature/tech" level instead of asking about science in-world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) tag has been one of those things on my to-do list that I kinda keep meaning to deal with and then keep pushing off again and again and again, and now it's . . . a bit of an issue. I feel like incorrect usage is something we should have been pruning regularly, but now the bush is so overgrown that nuclear options seem tempting.

I'm *inclined* to vote for the third option - some way of renaming it that makes the usage clearer, and updating the tag wiki accordingly; we could then map [science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) as a synonym of [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based). I'd at least like to *try* this, rather than get rid of it right away - give it a month of so, and see what happens. If, for whatever reason, people are still using it incorrectly . . . we might have to accept that it's a pretty niche tag, and might not be worth the trouble of keeping it around. The asking rate of questions that *need* it is quite low, so getting rid of wouldn't be terrible.

Regarding the name - I like [science-in-society](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-in-society), but I'd also like to hear other ideas.

Comment: Could also try [tag:science-as-concept].

Comment: The [tag:hard-science] tag is also long overdue for fixing. It is consisting misused by users who confuse it with hard-science SF (where SF is the better acronym for 'science-fiction'). This is a simpler fix. It only needs relabelling.

Comment: Seeing as people have had a week or so to provide input, I think a tag rename might be in order. I'm down for [tag:science-in-society] or [tag:science-as-concept], though I'm leaning slightly toward the former as it feels more concretely sociological and less abstract.

Comment: @Zxyrra I've performed the rename [tag:science] -> [tag:science-in-society]. We might want to synonymize [tag:science] as a synonym of [tag:science-based]; I think we'll also have to perform a good bit of retagging to clean up in the improper usage of [tag:science-in-society] on existing questions.